# Changing color of .accordion panels based on comment density

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

So I am trying to make every paragraph of a short story have comments underneath it when you click on them, and also have the comments change color in gradations of intensity dependent on the amount of comments in each paragraph.

It looks like this so far:

http://www.miraclejones.com/cathedral.html

I am using the "Easy Comment" Jquery plugin to put comments in each of my accordions -- and that works great -- but I have run into a hard wall when it comes to making the paragraphs change color based on the amount, or mere existence, of comments.

This was my last good idea, but I can't get it to work, and I don't know why:

```
     if ($("#paragraph1 .ec-comment-pane div.ec-total:contains('0')")>0) {
 $("#h31").css("backgroundColor","pink");}
 else {
 $("#h31").css("backgroundColor","green");
 }
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated.  I am a fiction writer and not much of a programmer, but I would love to publish my next collection in this style.  Let me know if you have any questions or if I can explain anything further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that, with length in the condition

```
if ($("#paragraph1 .ec-comment-pane div.ec-total:contains('0')").length >0) {
 $("#h31").css("backgroundColor","pink");}
 else {
 $("#h31").css("backgroundColor","green");
 }
```

or

```
color = function(){
  $('.ec-total').each(function(){
    count = parseInt($(this).text());
    if(count > 0)
       $(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content').prev().css("backgroundColor","pink");
    else
       $(this).closest('.ui-accordion-content').prev().css("backgroundColor","green");
  });
}
setTimeout(function(){ color(); }, 1000);
```

edit: added setimeout, because the ajax take some time to modify the text inside ec-total

Comment: Didn't work for some reason, although it seems like it should.  I feel like this particular .div tag is hidden somewhere or otherwise strange, on account of "Easy Comment."

Comment: I tried the second snippet, and it is extremely excellent code, and I can see how it would save time all over and I must already thank you deeply, but yeah, for some reason when it scans the '.ec-total' element it doesn't read anything as there.

Comment: I don't know exactly, which is why I asked in the first place.  Your code should totally work, but it doesn't for some reason.  I think the .ec-total element is populated some way through the easy-comment javascript, but I took a look at it and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: for your comment use $('div[id^=para]').EasyComment(); instead of writing it for each, and in the snippet add console.log(count)

Comment: Added these both in.  The "para" incrementer is fantastic, but adding the console.log(count) didn't seem to change anything.  The code is running as you recommended at http://www.miraclejones.com/cathedral.html.  Note: when I ran my original code, it worked just fine until I put it up live.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful, man!  I would send you some free books, but all my books are free online already.  Thank you so much.  A pleasure to watch your mind work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$('.ui-accordion-header').each(function( index, element ){
 if( $(element).height() > 100 ){
  $(element).css("backgroundColor","pink");
 }else{
  $(element).css("backgroundColor","green");
  $(element).css("color","white");//nice contrast, just for example
 }
});
```

This will make large areas have a pink background, and small areas have a green background. Note that green is very hard to read black text on, perhaps you should also color the text white in there, or choose different colors. These colors were probably just as an example anyway I would assume.

Comment: Yeah, these colors were just arbitrary placeholders to see if the code was working.  This would look neat, but I am really going for functionality -- to color paragraphs that have comments nested beneath them.